# .forceignore glob pattern

Tags: .forceignore

I have a .forceignore file with the following line.

```
**/objects/**/fields/*__*
```

As I understand it, this should ignore any field file that contains a double underscore.

However, when I run

```
❯ sfdx force:source:ignored:list --sourcepath=force-app/main/default | grep fields
```

The output *does not* list, for instance `force-app/main/default/objects/account/SBQQ__somefield.xml`

First question: am I just flat out wrong about what I expect? I understand / believe that `**` equals any sub-folder. I'm trying to craft basically any path containing objects/ any sub folder with fields folder, and any files in that contain `__`

Second question, since this doesn't work, is there a known way to do this?

Comment: What version of sfdx are you running? What shell are you trying this in? When I add that line to my .forceignore, it does indeed list every custom field for every custom and standard object, as I'd expect.

Comment: Well. Glad to know I’m not crazy in my expectations. Using Zsh, and just updated sfdx this morning.

Answer (score 1):

Ok Peeps.

1. When testing glob patterns for .forceignore, please ensure you are writing to the .forceignore file, not the .ci.forceignore file that your ci system copies into place.
2. The ultimate goal I had was to ignore *namespaced* custom fields. Here's the glob pattern I settled on:
   `**/objects/**/fields/*__*__*`